# Groups, Subgroups and Proving $H=G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A bit confused on how to approach this question:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $36$, let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and let $x$ and $y$ be elements of $H$ such that $x$ has order $12$ and $y$ has order $9$. Prove $H=G$

I understand that $G$ has $36$ elements, also I think that since $x$ and $y$ are elements with order $12$ and $9$ which mean that $x^{12}=1$ and $y^{9}=1$, but I'm unsure from where to go from here to start proving $H=G$

Any hints/advice would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications) tells us that both $9$ and $12$ divide $|H|$.

Comment: yes! I was just looking at the order of the span group (which is the LCM)